How to make Javascript smooth scroll horizontally
I am trying to get my code to make my div scroll smoothly horizontally. Currently it is just jumping to position. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have provided my code and a JSFiddle for you to look at.
JSFiddle


document.getElementById('scrollLeft').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('flex')[0].scrollTo(0, 0);
});

document.getElementById('scrollRight').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let w = document.getElementsByClassName('flex')[0].scrollWidth;
    document.getElementsByClassName('flex')[0].scrollTo(w, 0);
});
html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 20px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
.flexItem {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

 
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="flexItem">1</div>
        <div class="flexItem">2</div>
        <div class="flexItem">3</div>
        <div class="flexItem">4</div>
        <div class="flexItem">5</div>
        <div class="flexItem">6</div>
        <div class="flexItem">7</div>
        <div class="flexItem">8</div>
        <div class="flexItem">9</div>
        <div class="flexItem">10</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button id="scrollLeft">Scroll Left</button>
    <button id="scrollRight">Scroll Right</button>
</div>



Currently it is jumping to the beginning and end of the scrollbar correctly, but it is not a smooth slide to the end, it is a harsh jump. I tried adding scroll-behavior: smooth to the css, but that did not change anything.

Try this
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 20px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; /* New line */
}


Your answer indeed works however, perhaps taking a bit more time to answer WHY would help more. Adding pertinent links to documentation may also help OP understand why your answer is acceptable.
